# NumberFormatException when trying to compile a simple java program

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

This is my code:

```
public class RetailMarket {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i,ch1,ch2,type,total=0,kg=0;
        System.out.println("What would you like to buy::");
        System.out.println("(1)Grains  (2)Oil");
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ch1 = Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine()); // exception thrown here
    }
}
```

Every time I run it, this is my output:

```
What would you like to buy::
(1)Grains  (2)Oil
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at RetailMarket.main(RetailMarket.java:16)
```

I am confused as to why this `NumberFormatException` occurred; could anyone explain why?

Comment: The error occurs when you run the program, not compile it.  It appears you don't have a console when you run this for some reason.  I suggest trying to run it on the command line.  BTW You shouldn't wrap the `System.in` more than once as it is likely to discard input.

Comment: Are you closing br1 on every iteration? Show us the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `null` to `Integer.parseInt()`. This means that `br1.readLine()` is returning `null`. The *only* way this happens is if the end of stream has been reached. This means that you have somehow managed to not initialise `System.in` properly. Try running the program from the command line with `java RetailMarket` in the same directory as the compiled class. This code works fine when I run it.

Also, you should consider catching `NumberFormatException` and keep the program running if the input is invalid e.g.

```
try {
    ch1 = Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // invalid input
}
```

Comment: @Matin If it worked, you might consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that exception if `br1.readLine()` cannot be parsed as an int.
You should either validate that this String contains only digits, or you should catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use BufferedReader, use a Scanner and read the Integer direcly without having to parse.

Try this :

```
 public class RetailMarket{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 int i,ch1,ch2,type,total=0,kg=0;
 System.out.println("What would you like to buy::");
 System.out.println("(1)Grains  (2)Oil");
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
 ch1 = sc.nextInt();
      }
   }
```